# Grouping and Totals

Tags: mysql, grouping

Okay. I have a table I need my results to look like this.

```
Month  Active_Total  SIHO_Total Active_Paid SIHO_Paid
2004-02   317            315       2620.19   1503.56
```

However I have a problem...The aforementioned table is grouped up. This is a healthcare type innoDB database with several different schemas and tables. In my attempt to isolate the SIHO members (which is all I'm really concerned with) I isolated the members that are not part of SIHO and created a table that contains only the members I care about. This table looks like this:

```
SCC PHID SID Care_Program Month Total_Paid
B11  abc  01   null      2004-02  120.76
B11  bcd  00   null      2004-02  98.40
```

The SCC is static, PHID and SID together make a unique key, Care_Program is irrelevant it was just for my tests, Month - everything needs to be grouped up by month, so for all records that had a value for total paid, they should be summed up and displayed like this:

```
  Month SIHO_Total SIHO_Paid
2004-02   2           219.16 or whatever
```

I basically need the second table to look like this.

How can I group up these PHIDs to get counts where the member was in that month???

If you need anymore information please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean its obviously a sum(total_paid) I am more concerned about the COUNT(IF(PHID == true???)(logic not syntax) where Total_Paid is null? IDK i want it to be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my first step was to aggregate these tables. I broke down the problem into two parts in order to achieve my final results table. The first part is ActiveMembersPerMonth, which reflects:

```
month    total
2004-02    5
```

For this I created a routine to handle the grouping here is what my stored procedure looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ActiveMembersPerMonth`(sStartMonth VARCHAR(10), sEndMonth VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE dStartMonth DATE DEFAULT DB.ConvertYearMonthDate(sStartMonth,False);
DECLARE dEndMonth DATE DEFAULT DB.ConvertYearMonthDate(sEndMonth,True);
DECLARE curMonthStart DATE;
DECLARE curMonthEnd DATE;
    DECLARE curMonthStr CHAR(7);


TRUNCATE DB.ActiveMembersPerMonth_;

SET curMonthStart = dStartMonth;
WHILE curMonthStart<=dEndMonth DO
    SET curMonthEnd = LAST_DAY(curMonthStart);
SET curMonthStr = date_format(curMonthStart,'%Y-%m');

    INSERT INTO DB.ActiveMembersPerMonth
        SELECT eh.SCC, eh.PHID, eh.SID, eh.CID, eh.CGID, curMonthStr,count(*),sum(IF(m.membership='Employee',1,0)),
        sum(IF(m.membership<>'Employee',1,0)),null 
  from DB.table_SIHO eh
  join DB.Membership m on eh.SCC=m.SCC and eh.PHID=m.PHID
        and eh.SID=m.SID
  WHERE eh.Enroll_Date<=curMonthStart AND (eh.Disenroll_Date>curMonthEnd OR eh.Disenroll_Date IS NULL)
  GROUP BY SCC, CID, CGID, curMonthStr;

    SET curMonthStart = curMonthStart + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
END WHILE;
END;

call ActiveMembersPerMonth_SIHO('2006-01-01', '2012-05-31')
```

The next part of the problem was to get the total_Paid and the associated month to match up with what I now have...which is:

```
Active_Total     Month
     5           2006-02
```

Now I have another table aggregate that has the month and the total_paid So I am just going to join these up with the months and active_Total that were created from my stored procedure....

```
CREATE TABLE Rx_Paid_
SELECT CGID, date_format(DOS, '%Y-%m') as Month, SUM(Amt_Paid) as Rx_Paid FROM    DB.Prescriptions
WHERE concat(Policy_HoldeR_ID, Suffix_ID) not in 
('M000560838','M000029518','M00002699','M00002769') and DOS between '2006-01-01'   and '2012-05-31'
group by CGID, Month;
```

Same thing for Services -

```
CREATE TABLE Services_Paid;
SELECT CGID, date_format(Serv_Beg_Date, '%Y-%m') as Month, SUM(Amt_Paid) as    Services_Paid FROM DB.Services
WHERE concat(PHID, SID) not in    ('M000560838','M000029518','M00002699','M00002769') and Beg_Date between '2006-01- 01' and '2012-05-31'
group by CGID, Month;
```

Essentially I achieve my desired result in my group by. I had the total_paid in the first mentioned table. All I had to do was group by the month and an Identifier (ClientGroupID) (Group Level Identifier)

```
CGID   Month  Active  Service_Paid Rx_Paid
128 2006-01 314    2620.19      0.00
128 2006-02 330    4880.46      0.00
128 2006-03 344    29312.00      0.00
128 2006-04 359    15177.99      0.00
128 2006-05 386    774.58       0.00
128 2006-06 421    5966.52      0.00
```